# Создание бота для онлайн-игр

Tags: машинное-обучение, бот

Доброго времени. Решил написать бота для онлайн-игр (типа HearthStone). Опыта немного, и никто из друзей не хочет помочь. Я разбил задачу на несколько модулей:

1. Считывание изображения с экрана и нахождение на нём образов карт
   (все данные о картах есть в базе данных, привязаны к определённому образу),
2. Сам алгоритм действий,
3. Симулирование нажатий на сенсорный экран.

С первым вроде проблем нет. Это что-то типа Nomad должно быть.

Второе вот сложнее. Как создать алгоритм, и на чём? Использовать ли машинное обучение, и есть ли простые методы достижения цели?

К пункту три вопрос один: какие существуют технологии в онлайн-играх для борьбы с ботами?

Comment: книжки почитайте на эту тему

Comment: Разбейте Ваш вопрос на два отдельных. Один про алгоритмы и второй про технологии анти-бот.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По первому пункту - возьмите например библиотеку компьютерного зрения [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), есть привязка к Python.

По второму пункту - алгоритм конечно же зависит от игры, для того же hearthstone можно попробовать выбор действий в зависимости от вероятностей выпадения той или иной карты (как в покере). Вариант с машинным обучением для hearthstone потребует большое кол-во партий, и если удастся найти готовую базу сыгранных партий - хорошо, если нет, то наигрывать их займет много времени.

По последнему пункту - нет гарантии, что вас не вычислят. И самая большая проблема, вы не знаете, где и как вас будут ловить. К примеру равномерное перемещение мышкой, или касания со строго определенными интервалами, могут быть расценены как действия робота (как противодействие вводим случайные задержки/искажения перемещения). Вас могут вычислить на статистике - если ваша история будет выбиваться из средней по больнице. Поймать на фиксированных действиях в определенных ситуациях (надо будет добавить какие-то рандомные ошибки в действия робота, чтобы быть похожим на человека).

Comment: На счет равномерного перемещения мышкой - сделать приложение под планшет